# Use column value as variable name in where clause [SOLVED]

Tags: sql, sql-server

Do we have any option to use a variable that is dynamically generated on where clause depending on column value?

Example:

```sql
DECLARE @FR int(11) = '12'; 
DECLARE @GB int(11) = '13'; 
DECLARE @IT int(11) = '27'; 
DECLARE @ES int(11) = '20';
/****** countries variables are automatically generated with a php loop from an array so they could be even more than 200  ******/

select 
    country,
    price
from Statistics
where
    price <= @country /* so, this variable must have the country column value as example @FR if the country value is FR*/
```

Do we have any chance to do it?

More details:

```
 _________________
| country | price |
|    GB   |   25  | /* NOT SHOWN as > @GB*/
|    FR   |   10  | /* SHOWN as <= @FR */
|    IT   |   15  | /* SHOWN as <= @IT */
 _________________
```

[SOLUTION] At the end i created a #temp table with the countries and price data, joined to the main statement and compared. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: Where is the variable `@country` defined/ declared?

Comment: What is `int(11)`?  That is not valid SQL.

Comment: you'd be better to have a second table in the database which defined these values, then you could just JOIN to it and set the criteria that way. And then the structure of the SQL would not be affected by the number of countries.

Comment: it was a fast generated test SQL , the var are varchar(3) and countrys is not a variable but has to be the dynamic value depends on the country column value

Comment: Based on the names, price is a numeric column and country is either a name, an abbreviation, or a foreign key / ID value. So why would you be comparing a column named price to a variable that appears to represent a price for a specific country? That seems to be a logic flaw even if it "worked".

Comment: @SMor I think the concept is that if the country code input is `FR` then it would compare price with `12` (as per the variables at the top of the script). That's why a joinable reference table would make sense. Gordon's answer below shows what I mean.

Comment: Yep, at the end i created a #temp table with the country and price data, joined to the main statement and compared. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean logic:

```
select country, price
from Statistics
where (price <= @fr and @country = 'FR') or
      (price <= @gb and @country = 'GB') or
      (price <= @it and @country = 'it') or
      (price <= @es and @country = 'es');
```

However, a more natural way to phrase this would use tables:

```
create table country_prices as (
    country varchar(2),
    price int
);

insert into country_prices (country, price)
    select 'FR', 12 union all
    select 'GB', 13 union all
    select 'IT', 27 union all
    select 'ES', 20 ;
```

Then the query would just be a `join`:

```
select country, price
from Statistics s join
     country_prices cp
     on cs.price <= cp.price and
        cp.country = @country;
```

Comment: I would've said this too, however OP has said there could be up to/ more than 200 countries

Comment: Not sure about it, but I think `country` is a field name, not a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can do it usng case when

```
select 
    country,
    price
from Statistics
where
case when country = @FR then price <= country_fr
when country = @GB then price <= country_bg
...

when country = @IT then price <= country_it
end
```

Comment: Not going to work. `price<=country_fr` is not a value (or expression resulting in a value), which is what is supposed to follow `THEN`. See more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql).